# How to change a datetime list item to datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dates from 2010-2019 that assorts the list based on the day of the month. It collects all the same days of each month through each year. For example:

```
date_list[0]

[datetime.date(2010, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2012, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2013, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2016, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2018, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)]
```

Now I want to go through each date and create a new list that finds the 5 days before and 5 days after. The new list for Jan 1 2010 would then include Dec 27-Jan 6. I try to accomplish this below.

```
start_date = dt.date(2010, 1, 1)
end_date = dt.date(2020, 12, 31)
window = dt.timedelta(days=5)


url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/OisstBase/NetCDF/V2.1/AVHRR/{0:%Y%m}/oisst-avhrr-v02r01.{0:%Y%m%d}.nc'
cur_date = start_date
for cur_date in date_list:
    for i in cur_date:

        print([i])
        date_window=list_dates([i] - window, [i] + window)
        url_list_window = [url.format(x) for x in date_window]
        window_data=xr.open_mfdataset(url_list_window).sst
        sst_mean_calc.append(window_data.mean('time'))

[datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)]
```

However, I get this error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

How exactly do I avoid this error and accomplish the task at hand? Ideally the code should go through each day and create / add to the list (`sst_mean_calc`) with 110 days worth of data (Dec 27 - Jan 6 for 2010-2019).

Comment: in your code, don't put `i` in brackets (creates a list). however, `date_window` would still only contain two elements ([date - 5 days, date + 5 days]). is that what you want? if not, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

you could take each date from your list and add a range of timedeltas, e.g.

```
import datetime

l = [datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), # a shorter example...
     datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)]

l_10d = [[date + datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(-5,6)] for date in l]

l_10d
# [[datetime.date(2009, 12, 27),
#   datetime.date(2009, 12, 28),
#   datetime.date(2009, 12, 29),
#   datetime.date(2009, 12, 30),
#   datetime.date(2009, 12, 31),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 1),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 2),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 3),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 5),
#   datetime.date(2010, 1, 6)],
#  [datetime.date(2010, 12, 27),
#   datetime.date(2010, 12, 28),
#   datetime.date(2010, 12, 29),
#   datetime.date(2010, 12, 30),
#   datetime.date(2010, 12, 31),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 2),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 3),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 4),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 5),
#   datetime.date(2011, 1, 6)]]
```